# C - Understanding pointers to pointers and modifying value at memory location

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

It's been a while since I've really used C, so I apologize if this is something that should be obvious and I'm just forgetting how pointers work. Basically, I have a linked list structure, in which each link has a score. I'm trying to write an algorithm which traverses my list and removes the link with the lowest score. My structures look something like this:

```
typedef struct linkedList_tag {
  struct linkedList_tag *next;
  int score;
} LinkedList;

typedef struct head_tag {
  int size;
  struct linkedList_tag *next;
} Head;
```

Where Head is the default first link in the list. My current algorithm looks roughly like this:

```
void removeLowest(Head *head)
{

  LinkedList** lowestPrev;
  LinkedList* current;
  int lowestScore;

  if (head->next != NULL) {
    head->size--;
    lowestPrev = &head->next;
    current = head->next;
    lowestScore = current->score;

    while (current != NULL) {
      if (current->score < lowestScore) {
        lowestPrev = &current;
        lowestScore = current.score;
      }
      current = current->next;
    }

    *lowestPrev = (*lowestPrev)->next;

  }

}
```

Now, I know this code won't work and I think I understand what it is doing. What I don't understand is how to modify the code to accomplish my intended goal.

My intention was to store the memory location of the pointer to the lowest scoring node in the variable "lowestPrev", and then assign the pointer value of the node after the lowest scoring node to this memory location. So, every time I encountered a node that scored lower than my current lowest score, I would hold the memory location of it's point in a variable:

```
if (current->score < lowestScore) {
  lowestPrev = &current;
  lowestScore = current.score;
}
```

and at the end, I would assign the pointer value of the next link at this memory location:

```
*lowestPrev = (*lowestPrev)->next;
```

However, it seems that "lowestPrev" (if I'm understanding this correctly) will not simple retain the memory location it was originally assigned to it, but update it's value every time the pointer it is pointing to is updated, here:

```
current = current->next;
```

Am I understanding this behavior correctly and, if so, how can I modify my code to accomplish my stated goal?

Comment: Not able to write a full answer, but a quick tip - you are never `free`ing the node that is removed. That is a memory leak

Comment: You don't need different structs for Head and list, just one struct named list_node for example

Comment: `lowestScore = current.score;` --> `lowestScore = current->score;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use a double-pointer for `lowestPrev`; it is `head` that maybe should be a double-pointer, but that is not necessary in this case.

It is possible that the lowest value in the list is in the first list-node, and if `head` pointed to this node, the value of `head` would need to be modified within the `removeLowest()` function. This would not be visible outside of the function, so a double-pointer could be used instead here.

But, since `head` is actually a pointer to a dummy node in this case, there is no need for this. The first list-node can be changed without modifying the head-node.

There are a few problems with the posted code. `current` is a pointer, so `lowestScore = current.score;` should be changed to `lowestScore = current->score;`. Another issue has to do with the double-pointer `lowestPrev`. Within the loop, this pointer is given value of the address of `current`, and then `current` takes the value of `current->next`. Before the loop terminates, `current` becomes `NULL`; but now `*lowestPrev == NULL`, since `lowestPrev` holds the address of `current`. This leads to undefined behavior (most likely a segmentation fault) in the line:

```
*lowestPrev = (*lowestPrev)->next;  // probable segfault
```

Getting rid of this double-pointer a first step in the right direction. But the actual removal of the node with the lowest value needs to be handled differently. To remove this node, the node preceding the lowest node needs to be connected with the node following it. One strategy is to keep a pointer to the node preceding the lowest node at all times, so that the appropriate connection can be made after the loop terminates.

Initially, `prev` and `lowestPrev` should be `NULL`; these point to the list-node previous to the current node, and the list-node previous to the lowest node, respectively. When the loop terminates, if `lowestPrev` is `NULL`, then the first list-node is the lowest, and `head->next` is set to point to the node following the first list-node. If the node following `lowest` is `NULL`, then the last list-node is the lowest, and `lowestPrev-next` is set to point to `NULL`. Otherwise, `lowestPrev->next` is set to point to the node following `lowest`.

Note that if dynamic allocation is used for the list-nodes (and for the head-node), this memory needs to be `free`d, and the removed list-node will need to be `free`d before returning from `removeList()`. Here is a modified version of the posted code. This function assumes that `head` is not `NULL`, as did the posted function:

```
/* Assumes that head is not NULL */
void removeLowest(Node *head)
{
    LinkedList* current = NULL;
    LinkedList* lowest = current;
    LinkedList* prev = NULL;
    LinkedList* lowestPrev = NULL;
    int lowestScore;

    if (head->next != NULL) {
        head->size--;
        current = head->next;
        lowestScore = current->score;
        lowest = current;

        while (current != NULL) {
            if (current->score < lowestScore) {
                lowest = current;
                lowestPrev = prev;
                lowestScore = current->score;
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

        if (lowestPrev == NULL) {              // first node is lowest
            if (head->next) {
                head->next = head->next->next;
            }
        } else if (lowest->next == NULL){      // last node is lowest
            lowestPrev->next = NULL;
        } else {
            lowestPrev->next = lowest->next;
        }
//        free(lowest);
    }
}
```

It may be possible to simplify this code a bit by recognizing that the `LinkedList` and `Head` structures are identical, and that the dummy `Head` node could be replaced by a dummy `LinkedList` node.

The implementation could also be changed to avoid the need for a dummy node altogether; one way of doing this would be to pass the address of a pointer to the first list-node into the function. Here is an example of how that might be done:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int score;
};

/* Assumes that head is not NULL */
void remove_lowest(struct node **head)
{
    if (*head) {
        struct node *current = *head;
        struct node *prev = NULL;
        struct node *lowest = current;
        struct node *low_prev = NULL;
        int low_score = current->score;

        while (current) {
            if (current->score < low_score) {
                lowest = current;
                low_prev = prev;
                low_score = current->score;
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

        if (low_prev == NULL) {                 // first node is lowest
            *head = (*head)->next;
        } else if (lowest->next == NULL) {      // last node is lowest
            low_prev->next = NULL;
        } else {
            low_prev->next = lowest->next;
        }
        free(lowest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed, working answer. It's been a couple years since I've done any manual memory management and this served as a very good refresher.